# sum a column based on another column in R, but skip the rows with NAs

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I have this dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  n = c(50, 40, 70),
  WC = c(.012, NA, -.02),
  Dic = c(.03, .06, NA),
  I = c(NA, -.09, .0)
)
```

I want to sum the values in column `n` if there is a value in column `WC`. If there are rows with missing values in column `WC`, I want to skip them (i.e., value 40 in `n` should be excluded from sum, because there is a `NA` in `WC` row).
Then, I want to do the same with columns `Dic` and `I` - sum the values in `n` only if rows in columns `Dic` and `I` have no missing values, but skip the rows with `NAs` - and store the three sums in a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R option :

```
result <- colSums(df$n * +(!is.na(df[-1])))
result
# WC Dic   I 
#120  90 110
```

where `+(!is.na(df[-1]))` returns 1 if the value is not missing and 0 if missing.

```
+(!is.na(df[-1]))
#     WC Dic I
#[1,]  1   1 0
#[2,]  0   1 1
#[3,]  1   0 1
```

We multiply this result with `n` and sum the values columnwise.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(-n, ~ sum(n * !is.na(.))))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#     WC   Dic     I
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   120    90   110
```